# bootstrap - change popover arrow color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've been trying to change the arrow color of the bootstrap popover and regardless of trying what everyone says to do it won't change.

Here is what I have:

```
.popover.top .arrow:after{
    border-top-color: lightblue;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.popover.top > .arrow:after{
    border-top-color: lightblue;
}
```

If that makes much of a difference.

Thanks for any help ahead of time!

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/VUZhL/2440/

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I need the color of the arrow to be light blue, not just the border, but even that won't work for me. Is it possibly something else somewhere in the code?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/VUZhL/2442/

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Yes exactly like that, but when I put that in my project the arrow remains white.

Comment: Did you try add `!important` rule?

Comment: I think your custom css is being overriden by the default bootstrap css file. Try adding `!important` after `lightblue` like this and see if that helps: `.popover.top > .arrow:after { border-top-color: lightblue !imporant; }`

Comment: @makshh Not until now and it works. Thanks! I've been trying to do this for too long haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your custom css is being overriden by the default bootstrap css file. Try adding `!important` after `lightblue` like this and see if that helps:

```
.popover.top > .arrow:after {
    border-top-color: lightblue !imporant;
}
```

If it does, then you need to move your custom css file **BELOW** your bootstrap css file so you can avoid the `!important` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> <<-- ADD THIS FIRST
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customStyle.css"> <<-- THEN ADD THIS
```